# connection in APNS server works from terminal but not from php server (IOS push notifications)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

if I run this:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
    -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey.pem:
```

by following the tutorial in [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) I can see the response and the connection to APNS server works fine.

Then in my php server, I have that code for example:

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '6bdccb83e15333b7dd29c5e45a20f7bc1b8291b52e1d017e0e41fceb9959e5ba';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'code';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

But I get a connection time out. What do you think it might be?

Comment: Do you have ports for APN opened on server?

Comment: @nerowolfe probably not. Any link on how to do that on an online server?

Comment: if you are using hosting and virtual server I am not sure you can (we could not find any hosting that allows that). In the case of dedicated server you can just open any from your server. You need to have open this ports http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4264?viewlocale=en_us&locale=en_us

Comment: It seems odd that you would be able to connect via "terminal" but not via PHP if it were a firewall issue. However, definitely talk to your provider. DreamHost shared hosting allows this (I have EasyAPNS working). Worse case scenario, you change providers or find an outgoing port that does work and find a proxy server.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I contacted my provider and they opened the 17.149.0.0/16 which are the APNS Apple servers. However, they did that only for outbound and not for inbound. Yet again, I have a connection time out while the same script can run in my local PC. What do you mean with proxy server? Can you give an example, maybe in an answer on what you did for example to set it up for a web hosting service. Thanks.